# VBA: How to determine whether the number is Integer, even if it's received as a Double initially, let's say 3.0?

Tags: excel, vba, ms-access, integer, double

My `isInteger` boolean should be able to resolve into the following boolean values:

```
2   --> True
3.0 --> True
2.3 --> False
2.9 --> False
4.0 --> True
5   --> True
```

I tried to use the following code:

```
Dim isInteger as Boolean
isInteger = (myNumber Mod 1 = 0)
Debug.Print (isInteger)
```

However the output is always `True` even when `myNumber` is 2.3, 3.4, etc.

How should I fix this?

Comment: `isInteger = CInt(myNumber) =  myNumber`  Assuming you're not dealing with numbers outside of Int's range. Mod only returns whole numbers

Comment: How should I change if it was to work outside int range? lets say long.

Comment: Replace Cint with Clng, I believe.

Answer (score 1):

You can use the `VarType Function`

```
Dim IntVar, DblVar, StrVar, DateVar, MyCheck

IntVar = 3
DblVar = 2.2
StrVar = "Hello World"
DateVar = #2/12/69# 

MyCheck = VarType(IntVar)    ' Returns 2
MyCheck = VarType(DblVar)    ' Returns 5
MyCheck = VarType(DateVar)   ' Returns 7
MyCheck = VarType(StrVar)    ' Returns 8
```

Where the return values are:

```
Constant            Value   Description
vbEmpty             0       Empty (uninitialized)    
vbNull              1       Null (no valid data)    
vbInteger           2       Integer
vbLong              3       Long integer
vbSingle            4       Single-precision floating-point number
vbDouble            5       Double-precision floating-point number
vbCurrency          6       Currency value
vbDate              7       Date value
vbString            8       String
vbObject            9       Object
vbError             10      Error value
vbBoolean           11      Boolean value
vbVariant           12      Variant (used only with arrays of variants)    
vbDataObject        13      A data access object
vbDecimal           14      Decimal value
vbByte              17      Byte value
vbLongLong          20      LongLong integer (Valid on 64-bit platforms only.)
vbUserDefinedType   36      Variants that contain user-defined types
vbArray             8192    Array
```

You can also use the `TypeName Function`

```
MyCheck = TypeName(IntVar)    ' Returns Integer
MyCheck = TypeName(DblVar)    ' Returns Double
MyCheck = TypeName(DateVar)   ' Returns Date
MyCheck = TypeName(StrVar)    ' Returns String
```

Comment: 2.0 or 3.0 would all give me vbDouble i.e 5

Comment: which is what I do not want.

Comment: That's because 2.0 and 3.0 are Doubles

Answer (score 1):

I was having a similar problem, that was not solved by @Random_Answer_Guy solution because the input was formated as text.

So what i did :

- Test if numeric
- If Yes, create an integer variable equals to the variable your testing
- Compare the 2. If they're equal it's an integer

It looks something like this :

```
Dim VariableTested as Double
If IsNumeric(VariableTested) Then
    Dim VariableToCompareTo as Integer
    VariableToCompareTo = VariableTested   'This will round up variableTested to the closest integer
    If VariableToCompareTo = VariableTested Then
        'Congrats, it's an integer
    End If
End If
```

This is probably the worst way of solving this problem. But at least it is one way of solving this problem. Which is better than nothing.

It will probably not help you since this question is 4 years old though ...

Comment: You've implemented the original [Tim Williams' comment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38796719/vba-how-to-determine-whether-the-number-is-integer-even-if-its-received-as-a#comment64963878_38796719), in a more verbose way and with an additional step of `IsNumeric` that doesn't do anything (`IsNumeric` is always True for all variables of type `Double`).

Comment: It's because i had a problem that was similar, but with data input could be strings, so i needed to check if it's numeric otherwise trying to convert from string to integer leads to an error

Answer (score 1):

I recently discovered a pretty robust way to check if a number is an integer or not. Here it is:

```
Dim num, roundedNum As Double
Dim isNumAnInteger As Boolean

num = 3.3
roundedNum = Round(num)
isNumAnInteger = False

If num = roundedNum Then
    isNumAnInteger = True
End If
```

If the original is equal to the rounded number, then the original must have been and integer in the first place.