# How can i trigger a msgbox if the number entered in the textbox is not a whole number?

Tags: excel, vba

The code is functional as it is, only thing that's missing is said msgbox that goes off when i enter for example 10.5, in which case it rounds the input down to 10 and gives output 2 and 5 in the listbox.
Code so far:

```
Private Sub btn_OK_Click()
    ListBox_output.Clear
    Dim inputnr As Long, i As Long
    inputnr = Val(Me.TextBox_input.Value)
    If Not IsNumeric(Me.TextBox_input.Value) Or inputnr > 100000 Or inputnr <= 0 Then
        MsgBox "invalid input"
    Else
        For i = 2 To inputnr - 1
            If inputnr Mod i = 0 Then
                ListBox_output.AddItem i
            End If
        Next
    End If   
End Sub
```

Comment: See [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38796719/vba-how-to-determine-whether-the-number-is-integer-even-if-its-received-as-a)

Comment: The return of `Me.TextBox_input.Value` is a string. Check it with `If vba.InStr(1, Me.TextBox_input.Value, ".") > 0 Then`.

Answer (score 0):

### Write an Integer Sequence to a List Box

```vb
Private Sub btn_OK_Click()
    
    ' Retrieve the text box value (it's a string).
    Dim InputString As String: InputString = Me.TextBox_input.Value
    
    Dim InputNumber As Double, IsNumberValid As Boolean
    
    ' Validate the value.
    If IsNumeric(InputString) Then ' it's a number
        InputNumber = CDbl(InputString) ' write it to a double variable
        If InputNumber >= 1 Or InputNumber <= 100000 Then ' it's within limits
            If Int(InputNumber) = InputNumber Then ' it's an integer
                IsNumberValid = True
            End If
        End If
    End If
    
    ' Exit if invalid.
    If Not IsNumberValid Then
        MsgBox "Invalid input """ & InputString & """!", vbCritical
        Exit Sub
    End If
    
    ' Populate the list box.
     With ListBox_output
        .Clear
        Dim i As Long
        For i = 2 To InputNumber - 1
            If InputNumber Mod i = 0 Then
                ListBox_output.AddItem i
            End If
        Next i
    End With
    
End Sub
```

Or you could go down this road:

```vb
Const MinValue As Long = 1
Const MaxValue As Long = 100000
 
Dim InputString As String: InputString = Me.TextBox_input.Value
Dim iLen As Long: iLen = Len(InputString)

Dim InputNumber As Double, IsNumberValid As Boolean

If iLen > 0 And iLen <= Len(MaxValue) Then ' has acceptible number of chars
    Dim InputPattern As String: InputPattern = String(iLen, "#")
    If InputString Like InputPattern Then ' all characters are digits
        InputNumber = CDbl(InputString)
        If InputNumber >= MinValue And InputNumber <= MaxValue Then ' limits
            IsNumberValid = True
        End If
    End If
End If
```

Comment: very thankful for your help, alex's comment already solved it ! thanks !

Answer (score 0):

Add a test for the number after the first checking like this:

```
Private Sub btn_OK_Click()
    ListBox_output.Clear
    Dim inputnr As Long, i As Long
    inputnr = Val(Me.TextBox_input.Value)
    If Not IsNumeric(Me.TextBox_input.Value) Or inputnr > 100000 Or inputnr <= 0 Then
        MsgBox "invalid input"
    ElseIf Int(Me.TextBox_input.Value) <> CDbl(Me.TextBox_input.Value) Then    'added
        MsgBox "not integer value"                                             'added
    Else
        For i = 2 To inputnr - 1
            If inputnr Mod i = 0 Then
                ListBox_output.AddItem i
            End If
        Next
    End If
End Sub
```

Comment: very thankful for your help, alex's comment already solved it ! thanks !

Answer (score 0):

you could force the textbox to be always an integer

in the Userform code pane place the following:

- before any sub or function

  ```
    Dim tbText As String
  ```
- among subs

  ```
    Private Sub TextBox_input_Change()

        With Me.TextBox_input
            If IsNumeric(.Text) Then
                .Value = CInt(.Value)
                tbText = .Text
            Else
                .Value = tbText
            End If
        End With

    End Sub
  ```

you could also implement the test for any limit value